# Azure DataFactory Can you directly rename a file?

Tags: file, azure-data-factory

I want to rename a file, in place, as part of an ADF pipeline.
I can currently do that by copying it with a new name and deleting after the copy, but that's slow for large files.

Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to do this natively in ADF, but would be a great use case for an Azure Function.

Comment: Is SMB an option? https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/4041042-rename-blobs-without-needing-to-copy-them / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files?tabs=dotnet

Comment: @mjwills are you suggesting setting up a step in the pipeline that fires an API request to the file hosting (e.g. Azure DataLake or similar) to perform the rename "manually"? That's certainly an interesting alternative approach.

Comment: @Brondahl May be worth experimenting with, to verify that the rename isn't actually doing a copy behind the scenes...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, no, there's isn't.

According you description, it's more related to the copy performance. If the copy active could be faster, then the file will be copied to the destination with new name faster too. You want the copy performance be faster, you could follow this document: [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

Data Factory doesn't support change the source file name directly. Not only the the file name, but also the file data schema.

I don't think it's a good choice to only change the file name with Data Factory, it more focus on data transferring.

Comment: I mean, the most performant copy in the world isn't going to help with copying a 5GB file, vs renaming it.

Comment: But this is certainly what seems to be accurate at the moment (at least in nice ways, through the ADF UI.) So +1.

Comment: Thanks @Brondahl. Like I said, in Data Factory, we can'tt rename the file in source. When the sink new file created(copy active finished and source file deleted), the rename action finished. It the higher performance, the litter time which copy active will take. That's why the rename action will be faster.